# Reading a csv file and checking if a specific column is negative. If true, write the corresponding rows to another csv

Tags: python, csv

so I'm reading a csv file and there's one specific column I'm checking if its values are negative or not. If negative, I want to write to another csv.

## Input csv file :

Number(column name) :
1
-2
3
-10

## Expected output :

Number :
-2
-10

Basically, should only write those rows to another csv where Number column values are negative

I have tried using pandas and csv reader:

## Pandas:

```
df1=pd.read_csv(inputCSVFile) 
df2=df1[df1[Attribute]<(0) == True] 
df2.to_csv(outputCSVFile,index=False)
```

## csv.reader :

```
with open(inputCSVFile,"r") as inputCSV:
    input=csv.reader(inputCSV)
    inputList=list(input)
    with open(outputCSVFile,"w") as outputCSV:
        output=csv.writer(outputCSV)

        indexNumber=inputList[0].index(Attribute)
        print(indexNumber)

        for row in input:
            if row[Attribute]<0:
                output.writerow(row)
```

What exactly is going wrong? For csv.reader, the output file is completely blank.

Comment: post input data from you file and expected output

Comment: indentation is broken

Comment: @h4z3 - in the actual code, the identation is right. But even with that the output is not right

Comment: Sorry guys, the numbers in csv file aren't getting vertically aligned

Comment: Yeah, I don't care about your "actual code". If we can't see what is where, we can't help you because it's not the same thing.

Comment: @h4z3 hi, please there's no need to sound so rude. I've just started python and I'm doing my best with what I can

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write '==True' after checking <0

Following a step by step approach with pandas:

1. Import pandas as pd
2. Read CSV using pd.read_csv
3. Make sure Attribute is number type
4. Create a new dataframe which contains values that are negative.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df1=pd.read_csv(inputCSVFile)
   df1[Attribute]=df1[Attribute].astype(float) 
   df2=df1[df1[Attribute]<0] 
   df2.to_csv(outputCSVFile,index=False)
   ```

Comment: Hi, what is the need of astype(float) ? Because I don't want to convert the values to float, just want to check if they are negative or not

Comment: Astype float is used just as a backup measure in case the column is read as a string by read_csv. You can skip this step and the code will give you a result. In your code just change df2=df1[df1[Attribute]<(0) == True]  to   df2=df1[df1[Attribute]<0]